# 2D Discrete Fourier of Piecewise Function

Tags: fourier-transform

I need to find fourier transform of the function below. I saw examples on fourier transform of piecewise functions but couldn't find example on 2d Discrete fourier transformation. If you could help me I would be appreciated. Thanks.
[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXZ4H.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try to learn MathJax for the future tasks.